# How to install package from launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

I am doing some programming in C++, and I am trying to install this package: [llvm-toolchain](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-8/1:8-3~ubuntu18.04.1)
However, When I type into the console

`sudo apt get install llvm-toolchain-8`

it says: `E: Unable to locate package llvm-toolchain-8`

Is there anyway I could install this package? There is no PPA, so I assume it is defaulty in Ubuntu. (I have Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Do you need exactly that package or are you just looking to install a compiler? If you need a compiler, `sudo apt install clang` should work.

Answer (score 4):

`llvm-toolchain-8` is the **source package**, i.e. only the source code that is used to build all these respective tools. One source package can correspond to one or more binary packages with possibly different names.

When you scroll [further down on the Launchpad source package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-8/1:8-3~ubuntu18.04.1#yui_3_10_3_1_1558200600300_59) you linked, there's a section **Binary packages built by this source**, which is what you want instead - the already compiled and ready to use software packages. You see links down there to packages like e.g. [`clang-8`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/clang-8).

Those binary packages are available from the Ubuntu repositories and can simply be installed like:

```
sudo apt install clang-8
```

However, `clang-8` is currently only packaged for Ubuntu 19.04 and higher. On 18.10 you can use `clang-7` and on 18.04 `clang-6.0` only.

Or more simply, just install the `clang` package which pulls in the default version for your Ubuntu release, without you having to care for the exact number.