# How can I add gtk+3.0 from launchpad to 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, synaptic, gtk3

Sorry, fairly n00b with Ubuntu. I've searched and tried a few results but not sure how I could add the repo into my Ubuntu 20.04 in order to install `gtk+3.0`.

I've read:

- https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/529-add-launchpad-ppa-repository-to-ubuntu
- [How to install package from launchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144327/how-to-install-package-from-launchpad)

This is the package I'm trying to install through `apt`
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/3.24.18-1ubuntu1

What is the correct way to enable it via source.list and such that I could do `sudo apt install gtk+3.0`? Or is the correct way just to manually install it by downloading the `.deb` file??

I have not try to use `synaptic` yet, I'd like to stay as vanilla as possible, should I be using `synaptic`?

Thanks

Edit:
The reason why I want to have the package is that I have source code that looks for `gtk/gtk.h` which depends on that `gtk+-3.0` package.

```
fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install this package specifically?

Comment: I am trying to compile some of my code and is looking for `gtk/gtk.h` which is from `gtk+3.0`. I was able to accomplish this in 22.04 which had the package directly off `apt` but not with 20.22.

Comment: `gtk+3.0` would be the *source package* for binary package `libgtk-3-0` and development package `libgtk-3-dev`. The -dev package is what you need for the header files. I'm seeing version `3.24.18-1ubuntu1` from focal main and version `3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1` from focal-updates main (20.04.5) - not sure what you mean by 20.22?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu hosts packages in Launchpad, but you don't need to download them from Launchpad. The same packages are available from the official repositories via APT.

---

To find out the package you need, go to https://packages.ubuntu.com, and search for the library name (here, `gtk.h`) in the contents of the packages. You can choose the version of Ubuntu (20.04 is `focal`).

[image]

The results are the following.

[image]

As you can see, the related packages are `libgtk-2.0-dev`, `libgtk-3-dev`, `4-cran-rgtk2`. Since you need gtk-3, install the related package with

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which helped me troubleshoot and figure out what was my problem. I've actually already installed those other packages: `libgtk-3-dev libgcr-3-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev` but it won't find it. It turns out the, when my `Makefile` never had the proper `pkg-config` call execute correctly.  After some tinkering, I found where the `gtk+-3.0.pc` located and prefixed the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` before calling `x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config`. It then finally generated the correct `--cflags` and was able to find the `gtk.h`.